# Literals Javascript

Tags: javascript, literals

i have code like this:

```
          query= `${prefix}
          Select ${this.arrmeasureGabung} ${this.arrdimensionkey} ${this.arrdimatribut}
          where{
              ?obs rdf:type qb:Observation ;
              ${this.arrquerymeasuregabung}
              ${this.querydimensiongabung}.
              ${this.queryqb4ogabungAfd}
              ${this.queryqb4ogabungBlck}
          }`
```

I want ${this.queryqb4ojoinAfd} to disappear if it has no value. So that only ${this.queryqb4ojoinBlck} is displayed. Can the selection be made in the Literals?

Comment: A literal is used to insert expressions/variables into strings, that's it. You can probably use something like `${this.queryqb4ogabungAfd ? this.queryqb4ogabungAfd : ""}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume `queryqb4ojoinAfd == queryqb4ogabungAfd`

`${this.queryqb4ogabungAfd || ""}`

OR

`${this.queryqb4ogabungAfd || this.queryqb4ojoinBlck}`

The first one will not show `queryqb4ogabungAfd` if it has no value but will show `queryqb4ojoinBlck` regardless.

The second option will show `queryqb4ogabungAfd` OR `queryqb4ojoinBlck`